# c# how to exactly find solution for int to float

Tags: c#

i have some problems with a code, so maybe you can help me with it.
it says float to int cannot be converted.
Maybe you have idea, how to change it, am a beginner so sorry for dumb questions..

```
int height, weight;
float cost = 0.5f;
Numbers Numbers = new Numbers();
Numbers.Cost(height, weight, cost);
```

Already a new class.

```
public static void Cost(float cost, int height, int weight)
{
    //Calculating the price of it
    float result = cost * weight * height;
    Console.WriteLine(result + "is the price");
}
```

Comment: Seems the third parameter of the `Cost` method is `int`.

Comment: Actually its as a new public void.

Comment: public static void Cost(float cost, int height, int weight)
    {
        //Calculating the price of it
        float result = cost * weight * height;
        Console.WriteLine(result + "is the price");

Comment: Check the order in which you pass the parameters. The first one is cost, but you pass height

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are few Problems with your code.
1) You need to assign values to the variables before you can use them. Here You didn't assign height and weight.
2)The order in which you are passing the variables must match with the order you have declared the parameters of the function.
In your code your function parameters order is:

Cost(float cost, int height, int weight)

but you are passing them in:

Cost(height, weight, cost).

So,its trying to assign 'cost' which is a float to 'weight' which is int.

Bellow I have given the Correct Code:

```
    namespace ConsoleApp2
    {
        class Numbers
        {
            public static void Cost(float cost, int height, int weight)
            {
                //Calculating the price of it
                float result = cost * weight * height;
                Console.WriteLine(result + "is the price");
            }
        }
        class Program
        {

            static void Main(string[] args)
            {
                int height, weight;
                height = 5;
                weight = 10;
                float cost = 0.5f;
                Numbers Numbers = new Numbers();
                Numbers.Cost(cost, height, weight );
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
        }
    }
```